# install python module for certain python binary

Tags: apt, package-management, python, python3

I am using ubuntu 16.04 and have installed python2 and python3. Default is python2.

I am trying to install a python module ([mapscript](https://pypi.org/project/mapscript/)) with this command

```
sudo apt-get install python-mapscript
```

because for some unknown reason I cannot use `pip` to install it (either in or outside of a virtual environment).

using apt-get the module is succesfully installed in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ but not in python3/dist-packages.

In my project I use python3.

Is there any way to apt-get install a python module for python3 explicitly? Module is supposedly compatible with python3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python module installed from apt are usually named python3-xxx, but for some reason, there is no python3-mapscript.

If you cannot install this module over pip, I can suggest you to try to make your own python deb package, you may find many tutorial on internet to achieve this.